# Footprint of L6226Q

Tags: footprint, qfn

The L6226Q H bridge is using a QFN32 package.

Actually in the datasheet, it has this layout:

[image]

and it was noted that the pins 2 to 8 are connected to the die PAD and the die PAD must be connected to GND pin.

I've made a footprint like this:

[image]

Does it make a difference ?

Comment: A difference compared to what? Your footprint seems right. What do you fear exactly?

Comment: I suggest seeking out the recommended footprint, and the recommended solder paste layer. The asymmetry might cause your part to get pulled off-center in reflow- though their eval board does use a footprint similar to yours!

Comment: @SpehroPefhany, additionally, the OP can ask their reflow operators to secure the part with adhesive before processing the boards, so that floating is not an issue.

Answer (score 1):

You might want to get ahold of ST's "PractiSPIN" software that will help with the thermal analysis, in particular for this purpose it will estimate the effect of thermal vias and a ground plane etc.

Their [eval board](http://www.mouser.com/ds/2/389/eval6226qr-953751.pdf) looks quite raggy from the layout, maybe there are a bunch of thermal vias under the QFN, or maybe it's just a crummy layout.

It does have a large ground plane on the other side of the PCB to help with spreading the heat (it's not used for connectivity), so I would assume there are a number of thermal vias.

[image]

Comment: Wow, what is the reason for that lumpy outline?  Is it something to do with "etch thieving"?